# What restrictions are needed on an SSH key to restrict to saving and writing files only via SSHFS?

Tags: ssh, security, sshfs

I want to restrict keys used for `sshfs` to ensure that only the `sshfs` process can use that key, ie it will be limited to the commands `sshfs` uses for writing and saving files and listing directories.

In addition to the options `no-port-forwarding,no-x11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty`(which I assume will not affect it) what other options should I add?

I am thinking in particular of the `command=` option and what `sftp`, `scp` options should go into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me this works:

```
command="/usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server"
```

(You could find out by yourself by watching the process list on the ssh server)

Even better you could point `command` to a shell script which checks whether the client had used the right command. Like this (simplified, untested):

```
#!/bin/sh
# We get SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND from sshd

# comment out for production!
echo "debug original command: $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" >&2

if [ "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" != "/usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server" ]; then
    echo "access denied" >&2
    exit 1
fi
exec /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server
```

Such a script would also make it possible to check for allowed args for sftp-server. Similar idea as for the well known `rrsync` script.

For the other possible "no-*" options. I guess you can use most of them, just try. They are explained in `man sshd` -> `AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT`

Comment: if the `sftp` command the only used by `sshfs` when it communicates with the remote, ie every single command executed on the remote is through `sftp`?